# How to send HTTP POST data in multipart/form-data to REST API in Perl

Tags: perl, lwp

I am sending POST HTTP request to a website REST API from my Perl script using multipart/form-data which requires basic authentication. I am passing some params as key value pairs in Content along with image file to be uploaded. I passed credentials in header with encoding. The response from the REST API is error code 422 data validation. My code snippet is below:

```
    use warnings;
    use Data::Dumper;
    use LWP::UserAgent;
    use HTTP::Headers;
    use HTTP::Request;
    use MIME::Base64;
    use JSON;
    use JSON::Parse 'parse_json';
    
    my $url = 'https://api.xyxabc.org/objects';
    my $imgmd5 = '3740239d74858504f5345365a1e3eb33';
    my $file= "images/1839.png";
    
    my %options = (         
            "username" =>  '___APIKEY___',
            "password" => '' );             # PASSWORD FIELD IS TO BE SENT BLANK
            
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive=>1);
    $ua->agent("MyApp/0.1 ");
    my $h = HTTP::Headers->new(
        Authorization       => 'Basic ' .  encode_base64($options{username} . ':' . $options{password}),
        Content                 =>  [
                                                'name'=> 'Ethereum',
                                                'lang' => 'en',
                                                'description' => 'Ethereum is a decentralized open-source',
                                                'main_image' => $imgmd5,                                            
                                                'parents[0][Objects][id]' => '42100',
                                                'Objects[imageFiles][0]' => $file,
                                                'objectsPropertiesValues[142][ObjectsPropertiesValues][property_id]' => 142,                                        
        ],
        Content_Type    => 'multipart/form-data',
    );
    
    my $r = HTTP::Request->new('POST', $url, $h);
    my $response = $ua->request($r);
    my $jp = JSON::Parse->new ();
    print Dumper $response->status_line;
    my $jsonobj = $response->decoded_content;    
        eval {
                        $jsonobj = $jp->parse ($jsonobj);
            };
                if ($@) {
        print $@;    
    }
    print Dumper $jsonobj;
```

The error is:

```
$VAR1 = '422 Data Validation Failed.';
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'field' => 'name',
            'message' => 'Name cannot be blank.'
          },
          {
            'message' => 'Language cannot be blank.',
            'field' => 'lang'
          }
        ];
```

What I am doing wrong? basically server is not getting well formed query string and headers as I understand. I am passing some 32 key value pairs along with image file to be uploaded in actual script and I have produced here a minimal script. I know that all the params variables are fine as when I post this HTTP request via postman, it complains with different error.

I executed similar query yesterday night via postman with different param values and it got executed along with image uploaded. But now both postman and Perl script are complaining. I need two things:
1.First why the POST request via postman is complaining?
2. Second I am building Perl LWP script to upload data to this website REST API and I need a functioning script as produced above.

I will obliged if someone helps.

Comment: Do we have to encode the params/key value pairs with content type multiform while sending data via POST or PUT?

Comment: Your main problem is that you are putting the content into the headers, not in the request.

Comment: @simbabque. ok but I am confused. How can I put the authorization in the request? Any example would help.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. That should clean matters up. You did the right thing, but you put it in the wrong object. I'm going to edit my answer some more to show you how to turn this into a more useful API client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Steffen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66830230/1331451) shows you how to do it the most simple way.

If you want a bit more control, and especially if you want to do more than one request, give my solution a go.

The authorization you're doing is correct. I would suggest you move that into a [default header](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#default_header) on the `$ua` object. That makes sense if you're making multiple requests.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON 'from_json';
use MIME::Base64 'encode_base64';
use Data::Dumper;

my $url    = 'http://localhost:3000';
my $imgmd5 = '3740239d74858504f5345365a1e3eb33';
my $file   = "images/1839.png";

my %options = (
    "username" => '___APIKEY___',
    "password" => ''
);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( keep_alive => 1 );
$ua->agent("MyApp/0.1 ");
$ua->default_header( Authorization => 'Basic '
      . encode_base64( $options{username} . ':' . $options{password} ) );
```

Note I changed the URL to a local address. We'll see why and how I'm testing this code further down.

For your request, you can use HTTP::Request::Common as Steffen suggested, or you can pass it all to the [`post` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#post) on your `$ua`. It takes a multitude of different argument combinations and is very flexible. We want to send a form with key/value pairs, and a header for the content type.

```perl
my $res = $ua->post(
    $url,                          # where to send it
    Content_Type => 'form-data',   # key/value pairs of headers
    Content =>                     # the form VVV
    {
        'name'                    => 'Ethereum',
        'lang'                    => 'en',
        'description'             => 'Ethereum is a decentralized open-source',
        'main_image'              => $imgmd5,
        'parents[0][Objects][id]' => '42100',
        'Objects[imageFiles][0]'  => $file,
        'objectsPropertiesValues[142][ObjectsPropertiesValues][property_id]' =>
          142,
    }
);
```

I've changed some of the modules you're using. You don't need JSON::Parser. Just the JSON module is sufficient. If you let LWP decode your content you can use [`from_json`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON), because the body has already been turned into Perl's string representation from whatever character encoding (probably utf-8) it came in.

It's now as simple as this.

```perl
if ( $res->is_success ) {
    my $json = eval { from_json( $res->decoded_content ) };
    print Dumper $json;
}
```

To debug this, I'm using [the `ojo` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/ojo) that comes with [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/release/Mojolicious). It allows you to create a web application in a one-liner.

In a terminal, I am running this command. It spawns an app that listens on port 3000, route `/` with any method, and returns a fixed JSON object for your code to receive.

```
$ perl -Mojo -E 'a("/" => { json => { foo => 123 } })->start' daemon
Web application available at http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Next, I am making a request.

```
$ perl 66829616.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'foo' => 123
        };
```

This works. But we don't know yet if we're sending the right headers. Let's look at that. Install the [LWP::ConsoleLogger](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::ConsoleLogger) module and load [LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere). It will dump requests and responses from all your LWP objects.

```
$ perl -MLWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere 66829616.pl
POST http://localhost:3000

POST Params:

.------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------.
| Key                                | Value                                   |
+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| Objects[imageFiles][0]             | images/1839.png                         |
| description                        | Ethereum is a decentralized open-source |
| lang                               | en                                      |
| main_image                         | 3740239d74858504f5345365a1e3eb33        |
| name                               | Ethereum                                |
| objectsPropertiesValues[142][Obje- | 142                                     |
| ctsPropertiesValues][property_id]  |                                         |
| parents[0][Objects][id]            | 42100                                   |
'------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------'

.---------------------------------+-------------------------------------.
| Request (before sending) Header | Value                               |
+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Authorization                   | Basic X19fQVBJS0VZX19fOg==          |
| Content-Length                  | 633                                 |
| Content-Type                    | multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY |
| User-Agent                      | MyApp/0.1 libwww-perl/6.52          |
'---------------------------------+-------------------------------------'

.------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
| Content                                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [ REDACTED by LWP::ConsoleLogger.  Do not know how to display multipart/for- |
| m-data; boundary=xYzZY. ]                                                    |
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

.------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
| Text                                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [ REDACTED by LWP::ConsoleLogger.  Do not know how to display multipart/for- |
| m-data; boundary=xYzZY. ]                                                    |
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

.--------------------------------+-------------------------------------.
| Request (after sending) Header | Value                               |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Authorization                  | Basic X19fQVBJS0VZX19fOg==          |
| Content-Length                 | 633                                 |
| Content-Type                   | multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY |
| User-Agent                     | MyApp/0.1 libwww-perl/6.52          |
'--------------------------------+-------------------------------------'

==> 200 OK

.---------------------+--------------------------------.
| Response Header     | Value                          |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| Client-Date         | Sat, 27 Mar 2021 11:01:31 GMT  |
| Client-Peer         | 127.0.0.1:3000                 |
| Client-Response-Num | 1                              |
| Content-Length      | 11                             |
| Content-Type        | application/json;charset=UTF-8 |
| Date                | Sat, 27 Mar 2021 11:01:31 GMT  |
| Server              | Mojolicious (Perl)             |
'---------------------+--------------------------------'

.-------------.
| Content     |
+-------------+
| {"foo":123} |
'-------------'

.---------------------.
| Text                |
+---------------------+
| {                   |
|     foo => 123,     |
| }                   |
'---------------------'

$VAR1 = {
          'foo' => 123
        };
```

As you can see, your auth header is there, and we're using the right content type.

Notice that the User-Agent header includes `libww-perl`. That's because you have a space at the end of the string you pass to `agent()`. Remove the whitespace to stop it doing that.

```perl
$ua->agent("MyApp/0.1 "); # append libwww/perl
$ua->agent("MyApp/0.1");  # don't append
```

---

If you wanted to turn this into a more extendable API client, you could use [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo) (or Moose) to write a module like this. Put this into a file `API/Factopedia.pm` in your `lib` directory.

```perl
package API::Factopedia;

use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST PUT);
use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON 'from_json';
use MIME::Base64 'encode_base64';

use Moo;

has ua => (
    is      => 'ro',
    lazy    => 1,
    builder => sub {
        my ($self) = @_;
        my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( keep_alive => 1, agent => 'MyApp/0.1' );
        $ua->default_header( Authorization => $self->_create_auth );
        return $ua;
    },
);

has [qw/ username password /] => (
    is       => 'ro',
    required => 1
);

has base_uri => (
    is      => 'ro',
    default => 'https://api.factopedia.org'
);

=head2 _create_auth

Returns the basic authentication credentials to use based on username and password.

=cut

sub _create_auth {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return 'Basic ' . encode_base64( $self->username . ':' . $self->password );
}

=head2 create_object

Creates an object in the API. Takes a hashref of formdata and returns a JSON response.

    my $json = $api->create_object({ ... });

=cut

sub create_object {
    my ( $self, $data ) = @_;

    return $self->_request(
        POST(
            $self->_url('/objects'),
            Content_Type => 'form-data',
            Content      => $data
        )
    );
}

=head2 update_object

Updates a given 

=cut

sub update_object {
    my ( $self, $id, $data ) = @_;

    # parameter validation (probably optional)
    die unless $id;
    die if $id =~ m/\D/;

    return $self->_request(
        PUT(
            $self->_url("/object/$id"),
            Content_Type => 'form-data',
            Content      => $data
        )
    );
}

=head2 _request

Queries the API, decodes the response, handles errors and returns JSON. 
Takes an L<HTTP::Request> object.

=cut

sub _request {
    my ( $self, $req ) = @_;

    my $res = $self->ua->request($req);

    if ( $res->is_success ) {
        return from_json( $res->decoded_content );
    }

    # error handling here
}

=head2 _url

Returns the full API URL for a given endpoint.

=cut

sub _url {
    my ( $self, $endpoint ) = @_;

    return $self->base_uri . $endpoint;
}

no Moo;

1;
```

The client allows injecting a custom user agent object for testing and lets you easily override the `_create_auth` method in a subclass or by replacing it in a unit test. You can also pass in a different base URI for testing, as shown below.

Now all you need to do in your script is create an instance, and call the `create_object` method.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use API::Factopedia;

my $url    = 'http://localhost:3000';
my $imgmd5 = '3740239d74858504f5345365a1e3eb33';
my $file   = "images/1839.png";

my $client = API::Factopedia->new(
    username => '__APIKEY__',
    password => '',
    base_uri => 'http://localhost:3000', # overwritted for test
);

print Dumper $client->create_object(
    {
        'name'                    => 'Ethereum',
        'lang'                    => 'en',
        'description'             => 'Ethereum is a decentralized open-source',
        'main_image'              => $imgmd5,
        'parents[0][Objects][id]' => '42100',
        'Objects[imageFiles][0]'  => $file,
        'objectsPropertiesValues[142][ObjectsPropertiesValues][property_id]' =>
          142,
    }
);
```

To test with our one-liner, we need to change the endpoint from `/` to `/objects` and rerun it.

The output will be the same.

If you want to extend this client to do additional endpoints, you just need to add simple methods to your module. I've done that with `PUT` for updating an object.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! using your approach, the modular one, now the HTTP POST query via Perl script is producing the same error as that of the query via postman.

Comment: Yes I have plans to build a class for the API using Perl's OOP feature but I have never used Perl MVC frameworks. But thanks a lot for the effort, I will be using some MVC framework like catalyst etc. in future.

Comment: Ok now I have to update the data sending so I am using PUT but when I replace post with put method in LWP us I am getting this error "Can't locate object method "put" via package "LWP::UserAgent" at postobjectimg.pl line 33."

Comment: @programmingzeal I didn't see there was an error in Postman. Let me have another look. // I just used Mojo for debugging because it's super easy to do. If you want to start working with MVC and you don't need big stuff, don't use Catalyst. Use Mojo::Lite or Dancer2 instead. Catalyst has a really steep learning curve. It's very powerful, but you probably don't know it yet.

Comment: If you don't have `put` in your LWP object it seems your version is quite old. https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/libwww-perl#L290 says we added `put` in 6.04 in 2012 (I'm a co-maintainer of LWP::UA, but I wasn't around then). Run `$ perl -MLWP::UserAgent\ 9` (that's backslash space) on the terminal to see your version.

Comment: If you can't update your LWP, you can rewrite my code to use HTTP::Request  or to use HTTP::Request::Common to make a PUT request, and use `$ua->request` rather than my lazy approach. What I did was quite lazy tbh. It sort of assumes you trust whoever calls your not-actually-private method, because you could run arbitrary methods on your `$ua`.

Comment: Yes I was having version 5.386 of lwp useragent which i now upgraded. are there any good learning resources for Perl dancer or Mojo::Lite? (Note: Don't know whether it is allowed to refer other communities here)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230440/discussion-between-simbabque-and-programmingzeal).

Comment: Ok i have another issue that image is not uploading to the web site via api. I used your approach for posting param values and these are successfully posted but without input image. I am putting .png image in same directory where the perl script is saved.              The image variable is                                                                                                      'Objects[imageFiles][0]' => "52.png",.              However when i try to post HTTP query via postman image is uploaded. Whats the issue with my perl script? Do I have to setup boundary thing ?

Comment: @programmingzeal please ask a new question for that. Only show the bit of code that does the uploading with the args. If you've got the LWP::ConsoleLogger working, show the (relevant) output of that too.

Comment: I solved it. Found another discussion on stack that  helped.

Comment: I solved it. Found another discussion on stack that  helped.

Answer (score 4):

Use [HTTP::Request::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common). To cite from the documentation:

> The POST method also supports the multipart/form-data content used for
> Form-based File Upload as specified in RFC 1867. You trigger this
> content format by **specifying a content type of 'form-data' as one of
> the request headers**. ...

It also has an example in the documentation:

```
POST 'http://www.perl.org/survey.cgi',
     Content_Type => 'form-data',
     Content      => [ name  => 'Gisle Aas',
                       email => 'gisle@aas.no',
                       gender => 'M',
                       born   => '1964',
                       init   => ["$ENV{HOME}/.profile"],
                     ]
```